Why $ \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl (\phi(q^n)^{\mu(n)} \biggr)= 1-q $?
Playing with Euler $\phi $ function (not to be confused with the totient function, here another reference), I found this curious identity (I calculated it for various $q$ with Mathematica and it holds)
$ \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl (\phi(q^n)^{\mu(n)} \biggr)= 1-q $
with $\mu(n)$ the Moebius function and $ |q| < 1 $
How that can be proved?

Hint: take logarithms and use Möbius inversion.

@GregMartin thank you for the hint, but I don't know how to use the Möbius inversion, I tried to understand through some examples, but I don't know how to use it here

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\varphi(q^n)^{\mu(n)}=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mu(n)\log\varphi(q^n)\right). $$
Now,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mu(n)\log\varphi(q^n)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\mu(n)\log(1-q^{nk})=\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\log(1-q^m)\sum_{d|m}\mu(d)=\log(1-q) $$
so
$$ \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\varphi(q^n)^{\mu(n)}=1-q. $$

Thank you for your answe! I still don't get why $ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\mu(n)\log(1-q^{nk})=\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\log(1-q^m)\sum_{d|m}\mu(d) $, do you use here the Möbius inversion? How?

@user967210 I defined $m=nk$, when $(n,k)$ runs through $\mathbb{N}^2$, $(m,n)$ ranges through ${(m,n), m\in\mathbb{N},n|m}$, I just used the notation $(m,d)$ instead because it looks better. I used the Möbius inversion formula for the next equality, that is
$$ \sum_{d|m}\mu(d)=\delta_{1,m}. $$
